# How Can I Save Image File To Another Host With FTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ftp, ftpwebrequest, webimage

I get my image file like this;

```
var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
```

Than I save my image file to my local like this;

```
image.Save(Path.Combine("~/Images", NewFileName), "jpg");
```

But I want to save the image file to another hosting.. How can I do this??

Comment: you can't use save here, you need to create new ftp request to upload the file to another host, save only works on current host.

Comment: Ok I know, but how can I change file format and can you give me an example using FtpWebRequest with WebImage??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784550/uploading-a-webimage-to-ftp

Comment: Yes, It can be exp to FtpWebRequest with WebImage.. But it is not answer to changing file format..